# stop liqibasew from logging migration results in prod

Tags: logging, liquibase, dropwizard

Stack:
Java 21
dropwizard
slf4j

How do I stop liquibase logging out of the migration (nothing changed)?

I use dropwizard YAML for the config

so far tried:

- set the logger : off (in the yaml)
- magic env settings (in main)
- jvm properties on command line

```
UPDATE SUMMARY
Run:                          0
Previously run:              29
Filtered out:                 0
-------------------------------
Total change sets:           29
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how you're running your migration, but I disabled the output like this.

```
updateCommand.addArgumentValue(ShowSummaryArgument.SHOW_SUMMARY, UpdateSummaryEnum.OFF);
```

```
CommandScope updateCommand = new CommandScope(UpdateCommandStep.COMMAND_NAME);
updateCommand.addArgumentValue(DbUrlConnectionCommandStep.DATABASE_ARG, migrator.getDatabase());
updateCommand.addArgumentValue(UpdateCommandStep.CHANGELOG_FILE_ARG, changeLog);
updateCommand.addArgumentValue(ShowSummaryArgument.SHOW_SUMMARY, UpdateSummaryEnum.OFF);
updateCommand.execute();
```

Comment: and how do I remove the changeset logs? ```Running Changeset: test-migrations.xml::1700562051729-66::gadi.eichhorn@pexapark.com (generated)
Running Changeset: test-migrations.xml::1700562051729-67::gadi.eichhorn@pexapark.com (generated)
```